# Huge object in a Redux store

Tags: react-redux

Ideally we would put in Redux the result of a db query that might be very,very large (100k+ rows).

Looks as an overkill to put the result in redux, is there a clean way to put a kind of hash or timestamp in the redux store and be able to get the actual data in my React component ?

In Java we could somehow overwrite the equals and hash so it doesn't go do a deep equals, making it a lot faster.

Comment: Why would you want a React component to receive such a large blob of data? Don't you want to perform some filtering/transformations on that data before it reaches the component/container?

Comment: nope, as we want to render the data in a chart or map

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. Are you asking how do you verify the data in the store is the same data on the react component and there have been no changes? The reason I'm confused is the immutable nature of Redux solves this problem. So there is no need for a deep equals or anything like that.

Comment: Let's say I've a big object , comparing a single field is enough to know if it's equal ( it's like a timestamp). I don't want redux searching into the tree for a difference. The raison why is that it's possible the difference is very small and it's deep into the tree of object. How can this 'inmutable'  nature fix this ? (I'm not speaking about the same object)

Comment: You could try a JWT. By default, if anything changes the token is invalidated. I don't know about the performance implications but maybe you should look into base64 or JWT or something of that nature

Comment: @SeanKelly, eventually we're going to use this, using a kind of token (we can generate unique id's ).  It's a bit a pity we can not create a kind of equals method for Redux that overwrites the default behavior. Now the solution is to have part of the 'state' outside Redux...

Comment: is it about complex structure with deep nesting? or are you going to normalize data into flat collections? (if you don't - better consider this way)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for here..redux is just meant to be a state manager. if you need a unique key, or a key based lookup, you could store the data hierarchically (bucket all 100k rows under a single key), and use a checksum as a key (or any other hashing algo). this is something you would put in the reducer.
you can't really expect a deep compare on a large object, that has nothing to do with redux.
You could also use the id's of the records as a key, for instance having something like :
{ "1-100,000": data, "100,001-200,00": data2}

Comment: Have you tried a custom shouldComponentUpdate in the component that displays this big object? You can put the timestamp or hash verification there

Comment: from react native you can assign a unique key to item react, like to id DOM, and you can get with AsyncStorage.getItem(key) , and could set it key with a hash md5 with data set , and compare with create a new item, but really i unknown  , how you render this big file, and if really is necessary

Comment: Redux doesn’t do deep equals which I think is your main concern. It shouldn’t be problematic to store the data in Redux if that’s what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Redux by default *does not* use deep comparison. https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#redux-shallow-checking-requires-immutability

There's quite a bit of information on that page, but distilled a little - Redux only checks if the object reference is changed.

It's hard to tell what the specific issue is without seeing any code. It may be possible that you're somehow putting your object too high up the tree, and Redux is traversing the keys on the first level of your enormous object. If that's the case, simply wrapping your object in the Redux state may help.

```
{
   huge: myHugeObject,
}
```

But really, that's more of a bandaid. If Redux is traversing your object, you're probably not quite using it right.

A code sample would really help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: If it's the same pointer it's indeed the same object, not really the scenario. What happens when ther is a difference and this one is deep into the object's structure ? How do I know the way redux is 'navigatin' an object structure to check for a difference ? I know that my object has a timestamp, if timestamp is different the objects are different, no need to check anything else

Comment: Redux will not know if you change something deep in the object structure without changing the top level object. This is a common source of subtle bugs while using Redux. It's very common to make a copy of objects you put in the Redux store, just to guarantee they can't be modified by other code. Of course, if you have a huge object, you might not be able to do that - and may have to rely on being very careful to not modify the object outside of the reducer.

Comment: Got this :-). In our case Object would have different pointers. It's a 100% new one coming from the db , but, with a little, very little, difference.

Answer (score 2):

This would be my suggestion for ultimate performance. Keep in mind, I've not tested this myself, but if I understand your problem correctly then I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

You need to store 100K rows of data and ideally you need this data to persist in the client-side. The best solution here is to use IndexedDB because you can do read and writes like a database while also having enough storage. Like Soleil recommended, I suggest you use `dexie` to interact with IndexedDB. You don't need it, but you certainly should have it because of the amount of flexibility it will give you.

You need to be also able to diff these changes, and that's not going to be easy without pushing the work off onto another thread. So, the suggestion goes:

```js
  async function seedData() {
    // serialize your data, hopefully have unqiue id field on each row
    const hundredK = toJSON(await fetch(source));
    // IndexedDB doesn't have tremendous write speed, so it may be better to chunk your rows into
    // 10k intervals for  seem to perform the best but vary based on PC / browser implementation
    const db = new Dexie("myDataSource");
    // set version of Indexed to use (1 is preferred for best compatibility)
    // and set the indexes
    db.version(1).stores({
      animals: 'id,type'
    });
    let mice = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < hundredK.length; i++) {
      mice.push({
        id: i,
        species: hundredK[i].species,
        type: hundredK[i][0].type,
        facts: {
          someText: "this could come from hundredK, but I'll hardcode it",
          someNumber: i
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

So now the data is in IndexedDB and you can query it at any time. Now you need a way to push the performance heavy parts onto another thread. Luckily there's `redux-worker`

```js
import reducer from './reducers';
import task from './task';
import { createWorker } from 'redux-worker';

let worker = createWorker();
worker.registerReducer(reducer);
worker.registerTask('DIFF_IT', function (a) {
  // do your diffing and expensive functions
  task(a);
});
```

Put your worker into effect

```js
  ...
  import { applyWorker } from 'redux-worker';
  // you can't have any external dependencies for your worker, so bundle them or find a way to inline them
  const worker = new Worker('./script.js') // alternatively inline an async function it with `greenlet-with-edge`
  const enhancer = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger), applyWorker(worker));
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, enhancer);
```

Pass your db into your component, and hook on the update. Apply your action

```js
// all in dexie docs
this.props.db.animals.hook('updating', (modifications, key, obj, tran) => {
  if ("species" in modifications) {
    this.props.actions.task(modifications.species, key, obj, tran);
  }
})
```

Comment: It's not an actual solution for us, but thanks for the detailled answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your main concern seems to be performance, although I would go with the suggestions that have been mentioned in the comments, i.e: use a smaller payload, You need to render a lot of data into a react component and you need it to be performant, to achieve this you need to use a windowed component, this will render only the visible rows, and render everything else on demand, making rendering really long datasets really performant, look into https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/ and just pass the data to the component

Comment: don't worry for the widget rendering performance, it's another question ;-)